# Run custom SQL script on app start

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core. I need to create some views and functions programmatically on the app first start. Is there a way to run some custom SQL code while EF is being configurated?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using code first with entity, you can try execute your sql scripts in migration:

First you need to create a migration:

```
Add-Migration RunMySqlScripts
```

Then in the generated migration file you can write your SQL:

```
// PLAIN SQL
Sql("Your sql code here");

// OR FROM FILE
var sqlFile = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"scripts.sql"); 
Sql(File.ReadAllText(sqlFile));
```

Then you run:

```
Update-Database
```

This will be executed only once.

Comment: Thank you! It work with some little changes: `var sqlFile = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory,"up.sql");        migrationBuilder.Sql(File.ReadAllText(sqlFile));`

Answer (score 0):

I use this class for myself. That will run the code only once after the  database was initialized.

```
public class MyDataInitializer
{
    public async Task InitializeDatabaseAsync(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var db = serviceProvider.GetService<MyCustomDB>();
        var databaseCreated = await db.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
        if (databaseCreated)
        {
            await GenerateData(db);
        }
    }

    private static async Task GenerateData(MyCustomDB context)
    {
        context.Users.Add(new User
        {
            Name = "admin",
            PasswordParam = "pwd",
        });

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        // or execute custom sql here
    }
}
```

And at the end of `Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ...)`

```
MyDataInitializer dataInitializer = new MyDataInitializer();
await dataInitializer.InitializeDatabaseAsync(app.ApplicationServices);
```

Answer (score -1):

Loads of approaches you could use here, personally I would either use StartUp with a Configure method or a static constructor on the EF context.